# Как поставить timeout на событие?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как перед скрытием контента поставить таймаут 5 секунд?

```
function hideLink(element) {
    document.getElementById(element).style.display='block';     
    document.getElementById('hidelink').style.display='none';
    return false;
}

<a id="hidelink" href="#" onclick="hideLink('super')">
Нужно чтобы это скрывалось через 5 секунд после нажатия на эту ссылку
</a>

<div id="super" style="display:none;">
   А это появлялось через 5 секунд после нажатия на ссылку которая выше
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например с помощью setTimeout ([вызов функции или выполнение фрагмента кода после указанной задержки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)):

```
function hideLink(el, id) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';     
        el.style.display='none';
    }, 5000);
    return false;
}

<span style="color: blue; border-bottom: 1px blue solid;" onclick="return hideLink(this, 'super')">
    Не нужно использовать гиперссылки там, где нужен лишь их внешний вид, но не выполняется переход по ссылке
    Нужно чтобы это скрывалось через 5 секунд после нажатия на эту ссылку
</span>

<div id="super" style="display:none;">
   А это появлялось через 5 секунд после нажатия на ссылку которая выше
</div>
```

Comment: А вон оно как, а я то сюда `document.getElementById('hidelink').style.display='none'` пытался воткнуть `setTimeout` Спасибо.

Comment: @СергейЛапшин нзчт. если ответ помог отметь его как правильный. и задумайся о том как должна вести себя система при повторном клике на такую ссылку. и повторном. и т.д.

Comment: Отмечу, ещё 2 минуты подождать. А про повтор не понял ничего

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, у пользователя в теч. 5 секунд будет возможность повторно нажать на "ссылку". должна ли система на это реагировать.

Comment: @СергейЛапшин, я внёс в твой код небольшие изменения, так код будет взрослее

Comment: Отлично, то, что нужно. А то у меня получалось в ссылке несколько ссылок.